# DynamoDB Scan with Higher-Level Interfaces

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I try perform `DynamoDBMapper.scan()`.
When I request `scan()` on small table alright. 
When I request `scan()` on large table with `limit` application is not response long time while request performing. So I guess `scan()` try get all items in table not how much I defined.

If perform low-level `AmazonDynamoDBClient.scan()` it works as I expect and return limited items.

I know about Read Capacity Units and this not so much but low-level method works fine and fast.

**So question: What am I doing wrong? What am I must do for `DynamoDBMapper.scan()` work correct and request exact limited items.**

My code snippet. Table size ~1 000 000.

```
    final DynamoDBScanExpression expression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
            .withLimit(1000);
    return getMapper().scan(MyEntity.class, expression);
```

Comment: Are you doing any filtering in your expression?

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like you are immediately returning the results of the Scan operation. What are you doing with it immediately after returning? By default, the DynamoDBMapper.scan(...) operation returns a kind of lazily-loaded list. If you don't iterate on it immediately (which includes not converting it to an ArrayList<> for example), then it should perform just as well as the lower-level operation. Any more info on this?